# Why does this mysql stored procedure not work when I add an insert

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

This works fine until I add this `INSERT` line in.

```
INSERT INTO related_new(input_id,related_id, post_name, tag_count)
```

I understand that I'm using a string in the where clause but how come it (seemingly) works when the `INSERT` line isn't added.

fyi.  the error that happens when the `INSERT` line is put into this proc is:

```
Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: '1,10350
```

This where clause is a test.

```
   DELIMITER $$
  DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS cursor_ROWPERROW $$
  CREATE PROCEDURE cursor_ROWPERROW()
  BEGIN
    DECLARE cursor_ID INT;
    DECLARE cursor_VAL CHAR(250);
    DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE;
    DECLARE cursor_i CURSOR FOR select ID, tag_hash as VAL from wordpress.related_questions where tag_hash = '1,10350' limit 3;
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;
    OPEN cursor_i;
    read_loop: LOOP
      FETCH cursor_i INTO cursor_ID, cursor_VAL;
      IF done THEN
        LEAVE read_loop;
      END IF;
      INSERT INTO related_new(input_id,related_id, post_name, tag_count)

  SELECT cursor_ID, wp_posts.id, wp_posts.post_name, count(distinct tt.term_taxonomy_id) as tag_count
  FROM wp_posts
  INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships tr ON (wp_posts.ID = tr.object_id) 
  INNER JOIN wp_term_taxonomy tt ON (tr.term_taxonomy_id = tt.term_taxonomy_id) 
  WHERE tt.term_id IN (cursor_VAL) 
  GROUP BY wp_posts.ID ORDER BY tag_count desc, wp_posts.post_date DESC
  limit 3;
    END LOOP;
    CLOSE cursor_i;
  END$$
  DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: it's because `INSERT INTO related_new(input_id,related_id, post_name, tag_count)` is not valid SQL.

Comment: show the related_new and wp_posts tables?